# How do I add the values of a column together dependant on another column

Tags: sql, join

It's quite a hard one to explain but probably (hopefully) an easy one to solve so I'll just explain what it is I'm trying to achieve.

I have a table where multiple logs can be entered for a day each as a seperate row, I then have a decimal as another column, I'm trying to create a summary for each day which would be something like

01/01/1900  | | 5.5

When there's one entry for the 01/01/1900 with 2.5, one with 3 in the main table so adding the values together for the day?

My only issue is adding the dates together if the dates the same, I was thinking something like

Select distinct date and joining it with a table that gets the sum of the decimal column where date is... and that's where im not too sure?

Any help would be great! thanks

Comment: look up [group by](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/)

Comment: You can use GROUP BY. Is it a Date column or DateTime column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is named logs with data like

```
log_date     | value
1900-01-01   | 2.5
1900-01-01   | 3
```

then your query is

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM logs GROUP BY log_date
```

Comment: Perfect! knew it was easier than I was making it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT [ yourdatecol, ] sum(yourdecimalcol) FROM yourtable
  [ WHERE yourdatecol = .. ] 
     GROUP BY [ get_ymd_from_date(yourdatecol) | yourdatecol ] ;
```

With such syntax you'll get sum of row sets, selected by the same datecol value. You may also want to approximate date ( e.g. taking only Y/M/D part from it ), if date contains H/M/ss and what you want is per-day sums. Optional parts I enclosed in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT log_date,sum(value) FROM logs GROUP BY log_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Summary
AS
SELECT
    DateValue,
    SUM(DecimalValue) DayTotal
FROM
    EventTable
GROUP BY
    DateValue;
```

Then

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Summary
WHERE
    DateValue = '1900-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 103) AS OutputDate, SUM(ValueColumn) AS TotalValue
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateColumn, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming a DateTime is used, lets call it logdate. I'm also presuming the other one is a decimal, lets call it logdecimal.

Using SQL server 2008 you can do (the is a type called date which is without the time-part):

```sql
SELECT 
CAST(logdate as date) as TheDay, 
SUM(logdecimal) as TheSum 
FROM logTable
GROUP BY CAST(logdatetime as date)
```

Using a SQL server without the type date, maybe something like:

```sql
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(10), logdate, 101) as TheDay, 
SUM(logdecimal) as TheSum 
FROM logTable
GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar(10), logdate , 101)
```

Regards, Olle

Edit: This one will work if it is a DateTime (including time part) you want to group as a date (not including time part). Looks like this was not the case in this question.